# TcpClient available on all platforms Unity supports?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, network-programming, unity-game-engine

I've read a lot of Q&A about using .NET's TcpClient in Unity, and it appears to be possible.  What I'm wondering, because I just got burned by investing many hours in a NetworkView solution, only to find out it isn't supported for Windows Store builds (this fact isn't listed anywhere in the docs that I can see).  If I write my client code using TcpClient, will it work on every platform that Unity 4.3 currently supports?  Mostly I care about Android, iOS, and Windows Store, but who knows what the future holds, and I'm using Unity because of the cross-platform support.

I would just test it myself... but I don't have easy access to all of these platforms, and don't have test code written yet.

I have 15+ years of network programming experience, so not afraid of using low levels, don't really need or want any 3rd party libraries... was only going with Unity's built-in networking because I figured it would be the one thing that for sure was supported on all platforms.

Edit: I'm currently using the free version of Unity, if it matters.

Comment: Interestingly enough http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses shows RakNet as supported when you click Windows Store.. yet the key component, NetworkView cannot be added when build is set to Windows Store, hmm.  "Trust no one"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supported on Android, iOS and Mac/PC.

It's **not supported** in *Windows Store Apps* and *Windows Phone 8*. I don't know about the rest.
More info on Windows platforms [here](http://www.markermetro.com/2013/11/technical/getting-even-more-games-to-windows-our-partnership-with-microsoft-and-unity/).