# Is WWW available on all platforms that Unity supports?

Tags: http, networking, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395890/tcpclient-available-on-all-platforms-unity-supports) I just asked, but I know it isn't good to have multiple questions in one, so making a separate question.

I know [Licenses Comparison](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses) shows that it is available on all versions (even free) of Unity on all platforms in that list.  However, I've found other mistakes/misleading info in that list, so I'd rather hear from someone with experience or someone from Unity.

Also, if I do end up using WWW, I'd need to use a long-polling design (where server waits several seconds, even minutes to reply).  Any issues I'll run in to on different platforms?

Main platforms I know I need to target: Windows Store 8 (Surface RT), iOS, Android -- tablets and phones -- probably desktops later (Windows and Mac)

[WWW reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html)

EDIT: I'll be using HTTP and HTTPS in case not obvious (not file: or ftp: protocols).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the WWW-class on PC standalone and Android builds. It worked well with both text and textures. Only platform that requires additional tweaking, that I know of, is the web player where you have to add crossdomain-settings for fetching files.

Comment: With your answer plus http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/143705-How-do-I-make-a-server-initiate-and-send-back-data-to-a-client and already reading about others using on iOS, I think I have my answer, at least for platforms I really care about.